# Taking in data from a function using _.clone(this.model.attributes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, model-view-controller, marionette

My issue is that I have a view and utils function that I am trying to connect with the model data.

In my view; I have a function:

```
getCalculatedData: function() {
    var calculatedData = utils.calculateAmounts(_.clone(this.model.attributes))
},
```

This retrieves my model data with a key/value object. Now in my utils function I want to retrieve that data so I can use calculations. So I want to make a function that does this:

```
calculatedAmounts: function() {
    //retrieve data from that
},
```

How do I retrieve those values. Lets say firstname, lastname, and state are all in that model that it is retrieving in my view. Do I create a variable hash that holds them like this:

```
calculatedAmounts: function() {
    firstname : this.model.get('firstname');
    //etc
},
```

How do I retrieve the values out of that object?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure to completely understand your question, but in your `calculatedAmounts` method, why don't you use the variable you passed when you called the method in `getCalculatedData`?

Your code would look like this:

```
getCalculatedData: function() {
  var calculatedData = utils.calculateAmounts(this.model)
},

calculatedAmounts: function(myModel) {
  firstname : myModel.get('firstname');
  //etc
},
```

Also, if you are going to modify your model in `calculatedAmounts` and do not want those modifications to mirror outside the `calculatedAmounts` scope, you should deep copy your model object.
One common way to do it is to use the [`extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method of jQuery. It would look like:

```
calculatedAmounts: function(myModel) {
  var deepCopiedModel = $.extend(true, {}, myModel);
  firstname : deepCopiedModel.get('firstname');
  //etc
},
```

**Edit:**
Also, avoid passing `this.model.attributes` to your `calculatedAmounts()` method if you want to use the `get()` method in it.
`this.model.attributes` is an `Object` object, and not a `Backbone.Model` object.

The `.get()` you will call if you pass `this.model.attributes` as a param is the method part of the Object's prototype, and not the method part of the `Backbone.Model`'s prototype.

Comment: Thank you this helps. Actually the reason why I used the clone was so I wasn't editing the data from my model. seperation of concerns. but this helps. thank you